# Configuring legend for ArcGIS API for Silverlight?

Tags: legend, arcgis-silverlight-api

I can't get the [simple Legend sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/2.1/samples/start.htm#LegendSimple) working with this [florida mapservice](http://map.floridadisaster.org/GIS/rest/services/Facilities/Critical_Facilities/MapServer) and the ESRI Silverlight SDK 2.1.

The names appear, but the tree doesn't get populated.

Anyone see why this code shouldn't work?

Here's my modified xaml:

```
<esri:Map x:Name="MyMap" Extent="-15000000,2000000,-7000000,8000000">
            <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="Street Map" 
                    Url="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"/>
            <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer ID="Florida" Opacity="0.6" Initialized="ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer_Initialized"
                                               InitializationFailed="ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer_InitializationFailed"
                    Url="http://map.floridadisaster.org/GIS/rest/services/Facilities/Critical_Facilities/MapServer"/>
        </esri:Map>

        <Border Background="#77919191" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="20" Padding="5" BorderBrush="Black" >
            <esri:Legend Map="{Binding ElementName=MyMap}" 
                         LayerIDs="Florida"
                         LayerItemsMode="Tree"                         
                         LayoutUpdated="Legend_LayoutUpdated"
                   BindingValidationError="Legend_BindingValidationError"       />
        </Border>
```

Running the sample with fiddler, I see a request sent to here:
http://www.arcgis.com/sharing/tools/legend?soapUrl=http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer&f=json&returnbytes=true&_ts=634254399369803267

However, no similar request is made when running my modified version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working for me when I change the Legend control reference to ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.  I was getting a compiler error when I tried to use the legend from the same namespace as the Map control, which is what they are doing in the sample.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<UserControl 
         x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:esri="http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/client/2009" 
xmlns:esriToolkit="clr-namespace:ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit;assembly=ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit"

mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <esri:Map x:Name="MyMap" Extent="-15000000,2000000,-7000000,8000000">
        <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="Street Map"  
                Url="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"/>
        <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer ID="Florida" Opacity="0.6" Initialized="ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer_Initialized" 
                                           InitializationFailed="ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer_InitializationFailed" 
                Url="http://map.floridadisaster.org/GIS/rest/services/Facilities/Critical_Facilities/MapServer"/>
    </esri:Map>

    <Border Background="#77919191" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Margin="20" Padding="5" BorderBrush="Black" >
        <esriToolkit:Legend Map="{Binding ElementName=MyMap}"  
                     LayerIDs="Florida" 
                     LayerItemsMode="Tree"                          
                     LayoutUpdated="Legend_LayoutUpdated" 
               BindingValidationError="Legend_BindingValidationError"       />
    </Border>

</Grid>
```